# How do I get a variable value from javascript function to python function in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, qr-code

I am trying to scan QR code using html,javascript as shown below by nurse_home.html. I am able to scan and see the content of the QR code on the website but I can't POST the QR code output represented by

```
<output type='POST' id='result' name='result' placeholder='qrCodeMessage'>
```

in nurse_home.html.
I want to post it to the python function: nurse_qrscan in views_nurse.py so that it can be written into the database
Any help is greatly appreciated!
The following are the relevant codes:

<nurse_home.html>

```
{% load static %}

{% block mainbody %}


<title>Django Online Barcode Reader</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 
{% csrf_token %}

<script src={% static "js/html5-qrcode.min.js" %}></script>
<style>
  .result{
    background-color: green;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
  }
  .row{
    display:flex;
  }

</style>

{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div style="width:500px;" id="reader"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding:30px;">
    <h4>Scanned Result</h4>
    <!--<div id="result" name="result">Result Here</div>-->
    <output type="POST" id="result" name="result" placeholder="qrCodeMessage">
      {% csrf_token %}
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span class="result">'+qrCodeMessage+'</span>';
  }

  function onScanError(errorMessage) {
  //handle scan error
  }

  var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
      "reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
  html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

**Edited `<script>` tag**

```
  function getCookie(name) {
    let cookie = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + name + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
    return cookie ? cookie[2] : null;
  }

  function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<span class="result">' + qrCodeMessage + "</span>";
    sendQrCode(qrCodeMessage);
  }

  async function sendQrCode(qrCode) {
  const response = await fetch("/nurse_qrscan", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      result: qrCode,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      axios.post(ToDJ("nurse_qrscan"))   //**Newly added**
      }
    );
  }

  function onScanError(errorMessage) {
    //handle scan error
  }

  var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner("reader", {
    fps: 10,
    qrbox: 250,
  });
  html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);
```

<views.py>

```
def nurse_home(request):    
  return render(request, 'nurse_home.html')
```

<views_nurse.py>

```
@api_view(['GET',"POST"])
# Nurse scans QR
def nurse_qrscan(request):
    ### Test! nurse: QR
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Hi")
        result = request.POST.get("result")
        print(result)
        # Saving the result to database, nurse_QR
        # c = connection.cursor()
        # c.execute("INSERT INTO nurse_QR (output) VALUES ('{0}');".format(result))
        return Action.success()
```

<urls.py>

```
from hospital import view_nurse
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Main Page
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('nurse/', views.nurse_home),
    path('nurse_home/', views.nurse_home),

    # Nurse
    path('nurseLogin', view_nurse.nurseLogin, name='nurseLogin'),
    path('nurse_qrscan', view_nurse.nurse_qrscan, name='nurse_qrscan'),
]
```

**Actual database output (image 1)**
[image]

**Expected database output (image 2): 36987-2480**
[image]

**Error obtained from print(result) - Image 3**

[image]
(Since "Hi" is printed, in "view_nurse.py", it shows that "

> if request.method == "POST"

is working.
However, "result" is not printed, showing that

> result = request.POST.get("result")

is not working.)

**Multiple POSTS in the same QR scan - Image 4**

[image]

Comment: Why can't you post? What have you tried and how it failed?

Comment: I am trying to post the output of the scanned results represented by the <output type='POST' id='result' name='result' placeholder='qrCodeMessage'> in the html.  I want to post it to the function: nurse_qrscan in views_nurse.py. The web page sits on nurse_home.html shown in views.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `<script>` tag:

```
// Create a function to get the CSRF token
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookie = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + name + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
  return cookie ? cookie[2] : null;
}

function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    '<span class="result">' + qrCodeMessage + "</span>";

  // Call the function here
  sendQrCode(qrCodeMessage);
}

async function sendQrCode(qrCode) {
  const response = await fetch("/nurse_qrscan", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      result: qrCode,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // Do your thing here.
    });
}

function onScanError(errorMessage) {
  //handle scan error
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner("reader", {
  fps: 10,
  qrbox: 250,
});
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);
```

Let me know which part troubles you for further explanation.

Here is a breakdown.

First, you get the CSRF token from your form with the following:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookie = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + name + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
  return cookie ? cookie[2] : null;
}
```

Second, after generating the qrcode in the `onScanSuccess` callback, you invoke `sendQrCode` function with the qr code as argument:

```
function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    '<span class="result">' + qrCodeMessage + "</span>";

  // Call the function here
  sendQrCode(qrCodeMessage);
}
```

Third, you use Fetch to send a POST request to `nurse_qrscan` route:

```
async function sendQrCode(qrCode) {
  const response = await fetch("/nurse_qrscan", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      // You pass the CSRF token generated from the function
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
     // Create an object with `result` as property 
     // and the `qrCode` as value.
     // After that, convert it to JSON
     body: JSON.stringify({
       result: qrCode,
     }),
  })
    ....
```

It is a POST method because of `method: "POST"`

Following that, you write functionality to handle the data returned from your Django view:

```
async function sendQrCode(qrCode) {
    ...
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // Do your thing here.
    });
}
```

**Edit**:

> Could you elaborate on how the data returned in ".then((data) => { // Do your thing here}" can be handled? I don't quite understand what needs to be written in there?

In your `nurse_qrscan` view, you are returning something:

```
# import json at the top of the file
import json

def nurse_qrscan(request):
    ### Test! nurse: QR
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # parse the JSON data
        data = json.load(request)
        result = data.get('result')
        print(result)
        # Saving the result to database, nurse_QR
        # c = connection.cursor()
        # c.execute("INSERT INTO nurse_QR (output) VALUES ('{0}');".format(result))
        return Action.success()
```

When it receives the POST request from `fetch()`, it will return `Action.success`. I can't tell if its JSON or if you want to do something with the returned value to the frontend. If you want to access the value in Frontend using JavaScript.

Assuming it is JSON, you can do this:

```
...
.then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data) // log the data returned from Django
    });
}
```

In the line `.then((response) => response.json())`, The value returned from the view(if JSON), it is parsed into native JavaScript.

After the data is parsed, you can log it in the console or append in the DOM depending on your use case:

```
.then((data) => {
      console.log(data) // log the data returned from Django
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I have a query about the last portion where you mention to write functionality to handle the data returned from Django view. Could you elaborate on how the data returned in ".then((data) => { // Do your thing here}" can be handled? I don't quite understand what needs to be written in there?

Comment: Is the following code what you mean? Is the following code what you mean .then((data) => { axios.post(ToDJ("nurse_qrscan")) } .  I seem to be getting a bunch of values 0 in the database instead of the QR code's value.

Comment: I have made an update to my answer addressing your question. Let me know if that clears up your doubts.

Comment: I have tried the method above but I am still unable to write the QR code value into the database connected as shown in views_nurse.py. Only after that will the action be successful. If I simply log the data returned from Django without adding "axios.post(ToDJ("nurse_qrscan")" to ".then((data) => {console.log(data)}, nothing gets written into the database. 
On the other hand, with axios.post, I seem to be getting a bunch of values "0" shown in the first image instead of the expected output value (second image).

Comment: I have updated the problem in the original post for your reference. The newly added parts are the script tag but with the addition of "axios.post(ToDJ("nurse_qrscan")) " in the "async function" , and 2 images (expected output and actual output on database). Hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: I have made another update to the answer.

Comment: When you mention to check the value logged in the console, are you referring to the value from the terminal which I run "python manage.py runserver" from or is it the website? The expected output does appear on my website in the form shown in image 2 but when I log the value in the terminal using print(result), it returns "None" and the error: "Internal server error: /nurse_qrscan" and "AssertionError ... <class "NoneType">". You can refer to image 3 that I just uploaded above.

Comment: It could be that fetch sent the value(the qrcode  in the Fetch body) may be empty or undefined  and that is why `request.POST.get("result")`  have a none type. It proves that Fetch sends the request to the view, but the value(qr code value) could be the issue.  And this is why I also asked you to also log the value in sendQrCode(qrCode)  function to verify that it is not empty.

Comment: Oh i get it. Thank for explaining! I have logged the value to sendQrCode(qrCode) function and it is empty. Do you know why the result obtained is none type and how do i go about solving it?

Comment: Does this line  `    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<span class="result">' + qrCodeMessage + "</span>";`  inside the `onScanSuccess()` function work?  Because we call     `sendQrCode(qrCodeMessage);` immediately after it. If `qrCodeMessage` is empty, then the line before `sendQrCode()` should be empty as well.

Comment: Apologies, I wrongly added a line of code in the js portion. After rectifying it and logging the value in sendQrCode(qrCode) function and in Django view, I realised that `result = request.POST.get("result")` is not working. I have just updated the view_nurse.py and image 3 (showing the tested output) with remarks.

Comment: Hi, first, let me apologize. I just noticed that in the view, I wasn't parsing the JSON sent from fetch. So `request.POST.get("result") ` wasn't working because it couldn't parse the Data. It works if a form is submitted through button and not through fetch/axios. I wasn't able to notice this issue until you confirmed that everything else is in  place. I have updated the answer and it should be able to parse JSON properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It managed to work. Just a final question that I have, the current QR camera scans and posts the same value multiple times till the QR code removed from the camera (Image 4). Is there a way that I can do the following logic: "If current_scanned_value = previous_scanned_value, then ignore. Else, get the result of the scanned value"?

Comment: That is great news! you may mark the answer as accepted. About your question, I am not sure. I would suggest you ask it as a separate question to get fresh answers, plus to avoid confusing future readers with too many details since the main point of the post is getting a value from JavaScript to Python.